# Angular expression for ngoptions on concatenated array

Tags: angularjs, expression, ng-options

I have an array from the backend that contains an array of objects that are options for a select box, let's say for countryselection:

```
$scope.countries = [
    { name: 'foo', code: 'ba' },
    { name: 'bar', code: 'br' },
    { name: 'biz', code: 'bb' }
];
```

This array is raw and reusable, and may update at any time through different functions that may change this array.

However, I want the selectbox to be prepended with a different option that is initially selected and implementation specific (so will not add this to the countries array to not pollute it for other consumers of the values):

```
$scope.defaultCountry = [
    { name: 'Select a country', code: '' }
];
```

Then I want this to work:

```
<select name="countryCode" model="model.country"
    ng-options="option.code as option.name for option in defaultCountry + countries">

</select>
```

where the `defaultCountry + countries` would be a concat of the 2 arrays. However, this concat does not work.

I know I can call a function to return the concatenated value, but if not required I would rather not:

```
$scope.getCountries = function () { 
    return $scope.defaultCountry.concat($scope.countries);
};

<select name="countryCode" model="model.country"
    ng-options="option.code as option.name for option in getCountries()">

</select>
```

Is there an out of the box solution to be able to use both 2 arrays at once for ng-options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use concat in ng-options

```
<select name="countryCode" ng-model="model.country"
ng-options="option.code as option.name for option in defaultCountry.concat(countries)">

</select>
```

Comment: Very nice, this does not change the original array and still allows for any changes in the array to be reflected in the options

Answer (score 1):

This should do :

```
<select name="countryCode" model="model.country"
    ng-options="option.code as option.name for option in countries">
    <option value="">-- Select a country --</option>
</select>
```

Comment: This indeed works, but would rather not add html in the template due to the way it is set up (bigger picture not reflected here). Note that if the `value` attribute is left out, the option will be removed.

Comment: I use the exact same thing in my pages, the option doesn't get removed! I find this solution better than having to create and concatenate arrays. I guess it's a matter of preference! :)

Comment: My selectbox is actually a common directive, so updating that template to conditionally allow hardcoded options is a bit more difficult :) My ng-options does remove value-less option elements `<option>initial</option>`, but empty value fixes it: `<option value="">initial</option>`. Not sure why, angular 1.2.x.

Answer (score 0):

You can concat before ng-option :

```
<select name="countryCode" model="model.country" ng-init="allCountries=defaultCountry.concat(countries)"
ng-options="option.code as option.name for option in allCountries">
<option value="">-- Select a country --</option>
</select>
```

Comment: `ng-init` appears to run only once and will assign the allCountries property on the scope at that time. This value will not change when the countries change.